# How to remove first 3 and last 5 characters from account column in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, string, oracle

How to remove first 3 and last 5 characters from account column in Oracle SQL?

I have a column Account.
Sample account number "99k9220000709999"
The result should display the account number as "92200007".
Need Oracle SQL query.

Answer (score 2):

`substr` should do the trick - you start from position 4, and take the length of the column minus 5+3=8:

```
SELECT SUBSTR(mycolumn, 4, LENGTH(mycolumn) - 8)
FROM   mytable
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Serves the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Another method left-trims the part upto the character where the letter ends and then extracts the remaing string without the last five chars as

```
WITH t(str) AS
(
 SELECT '99k9220000709999' FROM DUAL
), t2 AS
(
SELECT regexp_substr(str,'[^[:alpha:]]+$') as str
  FROM t
)
SELECT substr( str,1, length(str)-5 ) as "Result"
  FROM t2
```

Answer (score 1):

Why make it simple if we can make it complex (for fun)?

```
SQL> with test (id, account) as
  2    (select 1, '99k9220000709999' from dual union all
  3     select 2, '002LF004828xx'    from dual
  4    ),
  5  split as
  6    (select id,
  7            column_value lvl,
  8            regexp_substr(account, '[^.]', 1, column_value) chr,
  9            max(length(account)) over (order by null) len
 10     from test cross join table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
 11                                              connect by level <= length(account)
 12                                             ) as sys.odcinumberlist))
 13    )
 14  select id,
 15         listagg(chr, '') within group (order by lvl) result
 16  from split
 17  where lvl between 4 and len - 5
 18  group by id;

        ID RESULT
---------- --------------------
         1 92200007
         2 LF004828

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with `substr()` and `length()`.  Another method is to use regular expressions:

```
select regexp_replace('99k9220000709999', '^.{3}(.*).{5}$', '\1')
from dual;
```

Not necessarily the most efficient way, though.

Comment: It is unclear what the OP would expect for a string shorter than 9 characters but this would leave the string unchanged as the regular expression would not be matched.

Comment: @MT0 . . . I was looking for a solution where I only referenced the string once.

Comment: `^.{0,3}(.*?).{0,5}$` [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4a11becd43c04ab05064092348b38ce6)